# Refresh in iOS simulator over VNC

Tags: ios, simulator, vnc-viewer

we have a mac mini, where we test over VNC-viewer our iOS app in iOS simulator 6.0 (369.2).

I guess after some system upgrades (now it's 10.8.3) VNC-viewer doesn't show simulator's screen changes and in order to see next screen, moving of simulator's window required.

I tried Ultra- and TigerVNC-viewer on Windows and Remmina on linux - seems to be - it's not the client. Everywhere the problem persists.

Does anyone have an idea, how to improve the situation?

Thanks in advance!
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4924818

I bet you don't have a monitor connected to your mac mini like me. I didn't use their trick but I can confirm once I hooked my monitor up to the mac mini it started working correctly. Hope this helps.